# Bold advanced math symbols

Tags: math-mode, bold, bm

I am looking to get bold math symbols beyond simple characters.  In particular, I'm having trouble with the following:

```
\bm{$a\xleftarrow{r} b$}
```

I've tried using several other packages besides bm, but all of them seem to yield the same

```
! Improper alphabetic constant
```

error.  Are there any packages that can handle these types of math constructs?  Or is there something simple I can add to the preamble to deal with this issue?  Thanks!

Comment: `\bm` should be used _inside_ the math.

Answer (score 6):

As described in the documentation of bm in 3.5 Strange failures you sometimes need to add braces to protect complicated commands. But in your case I would simply use \mathversion{bold}

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\bm{a\mathrel{\xleftarrow{r}}b}$

\mathversion{bold}$a\xleftarrow{r}b$
\end{document}
```

[image]